# How to retain validation error messages after reload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, reload

I am running several validations in my foo model. Here is how I am handling the create and update actions:

```
if @foo.update_attributes(params[:foo])
  #party time   
else
  @foo.reload #here is the issue
  render :action => "new" #or edit
end
```

I have to reload the attributes because I am using the default form values to run unrelated javascript. The problem is that by reloading the attributes, I apparently lose @foo.errors. Is there a way that I can pass them to the new reloaded variable? I would prefer this over using javascript to prevent the bad form submission. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reload method is obviously not for that. You can:
1. define your method for reverting the values
2. save the errors and then re-assign
3. merge attributes to the @foo from freshly loaded instance.

All of these solutions are very hackish and are not recommended. If I were you, I'd rethink the way things should work.

Comment: Welcome to my whole app. Thanks.